# URL Redirect on GoDaddy platform

Tags: plugins, redirect, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

I am the IT support person for one of our clients.  We have a domain hosted on GoDaddy in one account pointing to a WordPress site located in another GoDaddy account created by our client.

In the DNS we have an A record for www pointing to the IP address. We also have a 301 forwarding rule defined to send `http://example.com` to `http://www.example.com` which works perfectly.

What we would like to do is to forward the same way if a folder is entered, i.e., forward `http://example.com/folder` to `http://www.example.com/folder`. According to GoDaddy this cannot be done with the standard forwarding rule and should be done within the site.

Our client's employee who created the WordPress site does not know how to do this in WordPress.  I am not familiar with WordPress and I was hoping someone might be able to suggest an appropriate plugin to rewrite the URL to add `www.` when only the domain is used.

Comment: See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343) - you'll probably need to use the `.htaccess` rewrite solution.

Comment: On a subjective note, you might at some point consider migrating your client away from GoDaddy. Any host worth their salt should tell you how to solve such an issue. Based on personal experience, I group them in with the EIG hosts for leveraging a business strategy that prioritizes sales over performance or support - the price point starts low, but you get what you pay for and GD tends to be quick to upsell you instead of addressing questions and issues. I've also never really forgiven them for a decade of objectifying women to sell *web services* of all things. </rant> :)

Comment: note that these are not rewrites, these are redirects. I'm also not sure how this is a WordPress question, it looks like a generic Apache htaccess/config question that just happens to be on a WordPress site

Answer (score 1):

> In the DNS we have an A record for www pointing to the ip address.

You will also need an `A` record for the domain apex pointing to the same IP address. Or, preferably, an `A` record for the domain apex pointing to the IP address and a `CNAME` record for the www subdomain pointing to the domain apex.

You can then implement a standard non-www to www 301 redirect in the `.htaccess` file associated with the WordPress installation. For example, at the **top** of the relevant `.htaccess` file:

```
# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The above will redirect any request where the requested `Host` does not start `www.` and prefix the `www.` subdomain via a 301 (permanent) redirect.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect and make sure you have cleared your browser cache before testing, since the earlier (erroneous) 301s (by Godaddy) are likely cached.

NB: I've used `https://` in the above, but I notice you are using plain `http` thoughout your question?

Comment: Thank you for addressing my question rather than just ranting like the above comments.  I appreciate the effort.  I will forward this info to the developer.